# Organize symbols between input variables in output (C++)

Tags: c++

Hello few days ago i started programming in c++ language and encountered a difficult excersice for me, since english isn't my native language i decided to register here and look for help.

For example:

```
Input: 1 0 0 3  
Output:1>0=0<3
```

Since i'm beginner here i have no idea how to do this. Hope you guys can help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit your post with the requirements or assignment.

Comment: Right now im pretty limited at programming ive been doing mostly calculation programs and this is the first bit harder for me. Since i cant choose words correctly i couldnt find an answer in google.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int first, second;

    if (std::cin >> first)
    {
        std::cout << first;

        while (std::cin >> second)
        {
            if (first > second)
            {
                std::cout << '>' << second;
            }
            else if (first == second)
            {
                std::cout << '=' << second;
            }
            else if (first < second)
            {
                std::cout << '<' << second;
            }

            first = second;
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: On first glance the code looks good, but this is a code-only answer and doesn't explain to a new programmer what you are doing, why, and the process used to come to this conclusion. End result is training an new [Cargo Cultist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) rather than teaching a programmer. Second, and possibly more important, do you really think it's a good idea to do people's homework for them?

Comment: Given that the program is very simple, I'm not worried about the homework effect. The intention was to provide a working example which hopefully can serve as a starting point to understand the language basics.